# How to combine multiple table headers columns into 1 list

Tags: sql

How would I go about combining all columns headers for multiple tables into 1 list?

This works for a single table however I need to combine multiple.

```
Select name
Into output.Header_List
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('input.Table1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just use the "IN" operator and list all of the tables you need?

```
Select name
Into output.Header_List
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id in (OBJECT_ID('input.Table1'), OBJECT_ID('input.Table2'), ....);
```